# More Fragment flag and Frag Offset field after GRE fragmentation

Tags: ip, mtu, gre, fragmentation

If the length of a packet by attaching GRE-IP header results in bigger size than router MTU, what happen on More Fragment Flag and Frag Offset field of that packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, IP packets will need to be fragmented before encapsulation by GRE. The tunnel interface will have a smaller MTU than the physical router interface (physical interface MTU - GRE packet overhead). The tunnel interface is treated as a real interface, and the IP packets entering the tunnel will need to be fragmented before GRE encapsulation.

See [RFC 7588, A Widely Deployed Solution to the Generic Routing Encapsulation (GRE) Fragmentation Problem](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7588):

> **2.2. A Widely Deployed Solution**
>
> Many vendors have implemented a configurable GRE fragmentation
> solution. In its default configuration, the solution behaves as
> follows:
>
> - When the GRE ingress node receives a fragmentable packet with
>   length greater than the GMTU, it fragments the incoming packet and
>   encapsulates each fragment within a complete GRE header and GRE
>   delivery header. Fragmentation logic is as specified by the
>   payload protocol.
> - When the GRE ingress node receives a non-fragmentable packet with
>   length greater than the GMTU, it discards the packet and sends an
>   ICMP PTB message to the packet's source.
> - When the GRE egress node receives a GRE delivery packet fragment,
>   it silently discards the fragment without attempting to reassemble
>   the GRE delivery packet to which the fragment belongs.
>
> In non-default configurations, the GRE ingress node can execute any
> of the procedures defined in RFC 4459.
>
> The solution described above is widely deployed on the Internet in
> its default configuration. However, the default configuration is not
> always appropriate for GRE tunnels that carry IPv6.
>
> IPv6 requires that every link in the Internet have an MTU of 1280
> octets or greater. On any link that cannot convey a 1280-octet
> packet in one piece, link-specific fragmentation and reassembly must
> be provided at a layer below IPv6.
>
> Therefore, the default configuration is appropriate for tunnels
> that carry IPv6 only if the network is engineered so that the GMTU
> is guaranteed to be 1280 bytes or greater. In all other scenarios,
> a non-default configuration is required.
>
> In the non-default configuration, when the GRE ingress router
> receives a packet lager than the GMTU, the GRE ingress router
> encapsulates the entire packet in a single GRE and delivery header.
> It then fragments the delivery header and sends the resulting
> fragments to the GRE egress node, where they are reassembled.

And:

> **3.3.1.1. IPv4 Payloads**
>
> By default, if the payload is fragmentable, the GRE ingress node
> fragments the incoming packet and encapsulates each fragment within a
> complete GRE header and GRE delivery header. Therefore, the GRE
> egress node receives several complete, non-fragmented delivery
> packets. Each delivery packet contains a fragment of the GRE
> payload. The GRE egress node forwards the payload fragments to their
> ultimate destination where they are reassembled.
>
> Also by default, if the payload is not fragmentable, the GRE
> ingress node discards the packet and sends an ICMPv4 Destination
> Unreachable message to the packet's source. The ICMPv4 Destination
> Unreachable message code equals 4 (fragmentation needed and DF
> set). The ICMPv4 Destination Unreachable message also contains a
> next-hop MTU (as specified by [RFC1191]), and the next-hop MTU is
> equal to the GMTU associated with the tunnel.
>
> The GRE ingress node supports a non-default configuration option
> that invokes an alternative behavior. If that option is
> configured, the GRE ingress node fragments the delivery packet.
> See Section 3.3.2 for details.

[RFC 791, INTERNET PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791), has a complete discussion on fragmentation, including examples:

> Example 2:
>
> In this example, we show first a moderate size internet datagram
> (452   data octets), then two internet fragments that might result
> from the   fragmentation of this datagram if the maximum sized
> transmission   allowed were 280 octets.
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |Ver= 4 |IHL= 5 |Type of Service|       Total Length = 472      |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |     Identification = 111      |Flg=0|     Fragment Offset = 0 |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |   Time = 123  | Protocol = 6  |        header checksum        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                         source address                        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                      destination address                      |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             data                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             data                              |
> \                                                               \
> \                                                               \
> |                             data                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |             data              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>
>                    Example Internet Datagram
>
>                            Figure 6.
> ```
>
> Now the first fragment that results from splitting the datagram
> after   256 data octets.
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |Ver= 4 |IHL= 5 |Type of Service|       Total Length = 276      |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |     Identification = 111      |Flg=1|     Fragment Offset = 0 |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |   Time = 119  | Protocol = 6  |        Header Checksum        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                         source address                        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                      destination address                      |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             data                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             data                              |
> \                                                               \
> \                                                               \
> |                             data                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             data                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>
>                    Example Internet Fragment
>
>                            Figure 7.
> ```
>
> And the second fragment.
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |Ver= 4 |IHL= 5 |Type of Service|       Total Length = 216      |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |     Identification = 111      |Flg=0|  Fragment Offset  =  32 |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |   Time = 119  | Protocol = 6  |        Header Checksum        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                         source address                        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                      destination address                      |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             data                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                             data                              |
> \                                                               \
> \                                                               \
> |                             data                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |            data               |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>
>                    Example Internet Fragment
>
>                            Figure 8.
> ```